# Anchor link on single.php

Tags: links

My current demo site is http://www.dpimax.com/v2/ scroll down to news, so when you clikc on read more I want it to go to a specific anchor point on the single.php which I already have name #placeholder, the code I am using on the function.php for the read more is, I'm not sure how to integrate the anchor here, your help would be much appreciated.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
return ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '"> '
       . __('<br/><br/> Read More') . '</a>';
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ){
return 35;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
return ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '#placeholder"> '
       . __('<br/><br/> Read More') . '</a>';
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

I think that should do it.